# How to make Ruby Hash lookup faster?

Tags: ruby

What to do on a Ruby Hash, to optimize/fasten lookup ? (read only access)

Ex: freezing the hash, sorting the keys, forcing numerical keys...

Comment: What do you store in the hash? What are the types and sizes of the keys and the values?

Comment: Faster than what? Without any code or benchmark we'd have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use `frozen_string_literal`:

> `frozen_string_literal` reduces the generated garbage by ~100MB or ~20%! Free performance by adding a one line comment.
>
> Conclusion
> Gem authors: add `# frozen_string_literal: true` to the top of all Ruby files in a gem. It gives a free performance improvement to all your users as long as you don’t use String mutation.

*Mike Perham: Ruby Optimization with One Magic Comment, 2018-02-28: https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/02/28/ruby-optimization-with-one-magic-comment/*

Use `Symbol` as hash keys:

> If you use Ruby 2.2, `Symbol` could be more performant than `String` as `Hash` keys.

*Fast Ruby: https://github.com/fastruby/fast-ruby#hash*

Comment: Wow, # frozen_string_literal: true is very effective on my code !  +20% faster.. Thank you Timur for pointing out.